# Validate zip and display error with onBlur event

Tags: jquery

Check if zip is 5 digit number, if not then display 'zip is invalid'. I want to use onBlur event to trigger the display. But it's not working.

```
<script>
$(function(){

function valid_zip()
  {
  var pat=/^[0-9]{5}$/;
  if ( !pat.test(   $('#zip').val()   ) )
     {$('#zip').after('<p>zip is invalid</p>');}
  }

})
</script>

zip (US only) <input type="text" name='zip' id='zip' maxlength="5" onblur="valid_zip()">
```

Comment: Just to make sure, throw an alert in your function and check it's actually being called. Unless I'm missing something (quite possible), I'm not sure I like nesting your `valid_zip()` function in an anonymous function that's never called...

Comment: I use the alert trick and valid_zip() is not called. But why?

Comment: As I said, put it outside `$()` and make `onblur` lowercase.

Comment: Html is not case sensitive. onblur or onBlur should not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#zip').blur(function()
  {
  var pat=/^[0-9]{5}$/;
  if ( !pat.test(   $(this).val()   ) )
     {$(this).after('<p>zip is invalid</p>');}

})
```

you are now using jQuery, don't do inline coding...

```
<input type="text" name='zip' id='zip' maxlength="5" onBlur="valid_zip()">
```

should just be

```
<input type="text" name='zip' id='zip' maxlength="5">
```

Comment: I got you. It seems that avoiding inline coding is a consensus.

Answer (score 1):

It should look more like this:

```
<script>
        $(function(){

                $("#zip").blur(function() {
                        var pat=/^[0-9]{5}$/;
                        if ( !pat.test( $('#zip').val() ) )
                            $('#zip').after('<p>zip is invalid</p>');
                });
        });
    </script>

    zip (US only) <input type="text" name='zip' id='zip' maxlength="5">
```

Comment: Why prefer .blur() over adding onBlur event in `<input>`?

Comment: @phil: Yes we do, if we use JQuery. ;)

Answer (score 0):

`onblur` should be all lowercase.

```
<input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" maxlength="5" onblur="valid_zip()">
```

Also, why are putting `valid_zip` inside `$()` - you can just do:

```
<script>
  function valid_zip()
  {
    var pat=/^[0-9]{5}$/;
    if ( !pat.test(   $('#zip').val()   ) )
    {
      $('#zip').after('<p>zip is invalid</p>');
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: $() is shorthand for $(document).ready(). I just want the script to run after all DOM elements is ready.

Comment: You're just declaring a function - not calling it; you can safely do it outside `$()`

Comment: I have other scripts inside $() which are left out on purpose since it's not relevant to this specific discussion. So I need the function to be declared inside $().